# How to prevent RestSharp from adding the charset information to the content-type?

Tags: restsharp

I am trying to send a POST request with json string body by using RestSharp in version 107.
My problem is that RestSharp internally adds **"; charset=utf-8"** to the content-type string. Therefore my server answeres with "Unsupported Media Type".

The server accepts **"application/vnd.api+json"** but the request contains **"application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8"**.

```
        RestClientOptions options = new RestClientOptions("https://myserver/test")
        {
            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, 
            sslPolicyErrors) => true,
            Timeout = 60000,
        };
        RestClient client = new RestClient(options);

        string body = @"{" + "\n" +
                      @"    ""data"": {" + "\n" +
                      @"        ""type"": ""runs""," + "\n" +
                      @"        ""attributes"": {" + "\n" +
                      @"            ""inArgs"": {" + "\n" +
                      @"                ""A"":{""value"": 3.14}," + "\n" +
                      @"                ""B"":{""value"": 2.71}" + "\n" +
                      @"             }" + "\n" +
                      @"        }" + "\n" +
                      @"    }" + "\n" +
                      @"}";


        RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("/ressource", Method.Post);
        request.AddStringBody(body, "application/vnd.api+json");

        //...

        var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        //...
```

Is there a way to prevent RestSharp from adding the charset information to the content-type?

Answer (score 2):

Add `DisableCharset = true` to the options initializer:

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://myserver/test")
{
    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = ...,
    Timeout = 60000,
    DisableCharset = true
};
```